# Why some items in the contextual menu of OS X contain the selected file name but some don't?

Tags: mac-os-x, contextual-menu

Open `Finder.app` in OS X and right-click on a file (for example, `index.html`) to open the contextual menu. There are items *without* the selected file name like **Rename** and **Duplicate**, as well as items *with* the selected file name such as **Compress “index.html”** and **Quick Look “index.html.”** What's the design strategies behind this naming inconsistency? Or is it purely due to some historical reasons and does not have any UI/UX significants?

[image: A screenshot of the mac OS X dropdown]

Comment: Likely to be purely opinion-based, unless someone has inside knowledge of the OS X design team.

Comment: They could have justified this in their user interface guidelines, particularly when recommending to other developers on what naming conventions to use. I don't think it's opinion based.

Answer (score 2):

This is determined by whether the action is **bulk** (will be performed on more than 1 item) or **individual** (will be performed on each item at a time).

[image: A screen shot of the finder dropdown when more than one fine is selected]

As you can see, compress will act on all selected items, whilst duplicate will act on each item separately.

So the copy of bulk actions changes based on the selection, where that of individual items doesn't.

You could still argue that if there is only one item selected, bulk actions shouldn't have the extra text.